What is IP transit?
I came across "IP transit" as a product. I tried reading up on it but do not understand it. Can anyone explain in simple terms what IP transit is?

There are three main differences between an IP transit connection and your typical home/small business internet connection, or even a more expensive "dedicated" connection.

IP transit services are usually sold as a port in a datacenter. It is normally up to you to order cross-connects and/or transport services to get traffic from your equipment to the provider's equipment.
IP transit services are sold with the expectation that you may bring your own blocks of IP addresses and exchange routes with the provider over BGP. Broadband services almost never are, "dedicated" buisiness services may or may not offer such services.
IP transit services are usually sold with a "committed" data rate and billed on a 95th percentile basis. There is generally an expectation that customers will use most of the capacity of their link.

In general, IP transit services are what ISPs, hosting providers, and other large networks use to connect their networks to the parts of the internet they can't reach through peering.

Internet/IP transit requires you to have peered with the transit provider already (at an IXP or privately). Since you're peering you bring your own address block.
A simple Internet connection not only includes 'transit' to the Internet but also access through the local loop, FTTB, WLL or similar to reach your home/office building, and a dynamic or static IP address or even range.
